Usage of 直でこない in this sentence?

The characters are talking about archery and they explain that unlike other sports, while you fight with other people, you are essentially more like fighting a battle with yourself.
In the top bubble the characters adds

その分ダメな時メンタルのものすごい直でこねぇ

From context I can gather that he's speaking how mentally they fall part then? But I'm not quite sure how the grammar of the sentence is structured
メンタル直でこない?

来る can mean "to strike (psychologically)". See the 5th definition of this entry. 来ねえ is a colloquial version of 来ない. Here, メンタル(に)来る means "it impacts my mental (state)". 直【ちょく】で is simply a slangy way of saying 直【じか】に or 直接的に ("directly").

その分ダメな時メンタルものすごい直で来ねえ？
Because of that, when things go wrong, it hits your mental state really hard, doesn't it?

